# Does apple allow apps with custom keyboards?

Tags: unity-game-engine, on-screen-keyboard

This question might be posted before, but I was not sure it was correct in my case.

I am making an app in Unity 3D and I want to make an on-screen keyboard (not the phone's default keyboard). This will not cause any problems on Android, but is it against the App Store guidelines?

The on-screen custom keyboard will contain all the A-Z letters and it will be made out of GUITextures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but publishing guidelines.

Comment: Is it possible you can recommend any other forums that would be relevant for this specific quesiton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is against the App Store Approval Guidelines. I've seen apps use a built-in keyboard, just as long as you don't have to install the keyboard per device.